# How to set default value instead of null in deserialization

Tags: c#, json, wpf, json.net

After a deserialization I get some object null, this cause an exception in the deserialization so I've avoided the problem setting the appropriate property in the class:

```
[JsonProperty("jerseyNumber", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public int jerseyNumber { get; set; }
```

The problem is that after the deserialization, the value of the `int` is equal to 0 because in the JSON is null. 
I want set this `null` value to empty, how can I achieve this? 
I've tryed also with: `[DefaultValue("Null")]` but don't working because the value is an integer.

Comment: Forget about the deserialization bit. Can you, in your own code, set that property to `null`? (You can't.) If you can, please show how. If you can't, how would you change your property definition so that you can set it to `null`? Once you have that working, does that change your deserialization? (It does.)

Comment: `int` cant be null. instead use `int?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set int as `nullable` try as following:

```
public int? jerseyNumber { get; set; }
```